# why is android coming from background activity class "com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher"

Tags: android, android-activity, background, activity-manager

While the activity is on, I go to the background and when I want to learn the classname from within a service, I see "com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher".
I need the activity class. Where am I going wrong?

The codes I wrote for classname are as follows;

```
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) 
    getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
    ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    String className = componentInfo.getClassName();
```

Comment: are you shure that `com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher` isn't `Activity`? can you elaborate more what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @snachmsm  Of course, when I am in UserActivity, I put the application in the background and I want to get the class name using the above codes to find out what activity I am in from a service that continues to run. But when it is in the background componentInfo comes as "com.miui.home.launcher.Launcher". However, if it is not in the background, I can see the class name as UserActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.miumi.home.launcher.Launcher` is `Activity` set as devices launcher - "desktop" app responsible for showing all your apps grid, widgets etc. when your app is in background (put there by e.g. Home button) and any of your `Activites` isn't present on the screen then your device is showing Launcher app and this is reporting your code

note that `getRunningTasks` method is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningTasks(int)) and won't let you know which third-party app is on foreground. currently this method may only return info about your app or Launcher/"desktop"

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getRunningTasks(int)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So is there no way I can see the activity name before going into the background while in the background?

Comment: I used this    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> task = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        // Get the info we need for comparison.
        ComponentName componentInfo2 = task.get(0).importanceReasonComponent; but not working

Comment: it would be a bit insecure, would reveal users behavior - which app and how long was used. I'm not surpised that this isn't an option for usueal developer nowadays